# Making a "Select All" checkbutton in Python2.7/PyGTK

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

Using PyGTK, I am trying to make a ListStore with CheckButtons in the first column and a "Select All" CheckButton similar to what GMail and Yahoo! Mail have for quickly selecting or deselecting every CheckButton in the list. If it is toggled, all the buttons in the list should change to match it. It should also change to reflect the state of the individual buttons as they are pressed. (Checked if all buttons are checked, cleared if all buttons are cleared, otherwise in an in-between state) So I want the relationship between the buttons to be bidirectional, so they always stay in sync.

Here is my current attempt. Currently the "Select All" CheckButton works as expected, but clicking the buttons in the list only ever sets the Select All button to its in-between state, even though I have confirmed the 3-part conditional is working properly so its set_active method is being called as expected. Also, I am not sure how it doesn't get into an infinite mutually recursive loop as each callback triggers the other.

```
#store is a ListStore whose first column has been packed with a
#CellRendererToggle, checkCell

selectAllBox = gtk.CheckButton("Select All")

def OnSelectAll(toggleButton):
    toggleButton.set_inconsistent(False)
    value = toggleButton.get_active()
    def Toggle(store, path, itr, v):
        store[path][0] = v
    store.foreach(Toggle, value)

selectAllBox.connect("toggled", OnSelectAll)

def OnToggle(cellRenderer, path):
    value = not store[path][0]
    store[path][0] = value

    checked = list()
    store.foreach(lambda store, path, itr: checked.append(store[path][0]))
    if all(checked):
        selectAllBox.set_active(True)
    elif not any(checked):
        selectAllBox.set_active(False)
    else:
        selectAllBox.set_inconsistent(True)

checkCell.connect("toggled", OnToggle)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to `set_inconsistent(False)` when you don't want the checkbutton to be in its inconsistent state.

Also, GTK is usually pretty good about not triggering signals when setting an active checkbox to active, for example.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. My code for setting the checkboxes in the column when the "Select All" box was changed didn't trigger OnToggle at all, so there is no risk of an infinite loop. I just had to call selectAllBox.set_inconsistent(False) before calling set_active and it worked fine.